# EF core DataBase Update

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

Guys we moved Framework 7 to EF core 2.0 .So right now  we have a Small problem.

when We use Entity Framework 7 its mostly easy to update client Database without any doubt.(update -database)

but in EF core there is a problem the reason is for every changes we have to add add-migration so in that case we have now 100 migration history.

example :(20180313063924_NewVersion,14689013063934_NewVersion etc)

so when we update client database we have to keep that 100 migration history 
But i think this is not the good way  when its come to production level

is there  anyway to resolve this problem.it would be helpful so much thank you!!

Comment: Do you use code first? If I understand you correctly, the problem is that you have 100+ migrations? The project/database is still in dev-phase? Nothing was deployed?

Comment: yes we use code first and still we didn't deployed

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is exactly the way like EF and EFCore are working.

Every migration represents the needed modification on DbContext/Database to be valid with model's changes. So if you have changes, they will be represented by a migration.

One - in my opinion - not very clean solution could be:

1. delete current database
2. delete whole `Migrations` directory (is valid too to delete all migration files and `<yourContextName>Snapshot.cs` file in `Migrations` directory)
3. add new migration e.g. `InitialCreate`

The result will be only one migration that represents your current project's model/dbcontext state.
The approach is only possible if the project is still in dev-phase without any deployments on any stages.

Please note, I don't recommend that solution/approach. In my opinion you should leave the migrations like they are.

For further information you should read following:

1. [The Model Snapshot In Entity Framework Core](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/model-snapshot)
2. [Migration in Entity Framework Core](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-migration.aspx)

Comment: :D right now we are  using **1.delete current database** ,because still we are  not  in production level.  however  the solution is keep the migration file as its. if i found something use full let me post here thank anyway !!

Comment: I didn't understand what your solution is. Please explain more precisely.